# What is the correct way to collect data in react without Re-rendering and Perfomance Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects

imagine we have alot input field and bulky state like this to update it

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    gender: "",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    nationalCode: "",
    mobileNum: "",
    organizationalRuling: "",
    startOrder: null,
    endOrder: null,
    afterOrderEnd: [],
    cardNum1: "",
    bankName1: "",
    cardNum2: "",
    bankName2: "",
    shabaNum: null,
    country: "",
    state: "",
    city: "",
    address: "",
    zipCode: null,
    phoneNum: "",
    commissionFor: [],
    commissionPercentage: [],
    salaryFor: [],
    salaryPrice: [],
    offFor: [],
    offPercentage: [],
    username: "",
    password: "",
    passwordRepeat: "",
    userStatus: "activeUser",
  });
```

and we divided this big data in 6 component
for example BankInfo, AccountInfo, AddressInfo, and... we update state inside this component and we Use `ContextAPI` to pass state

```
        <DataContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
              <ListProfile />
              <OrganizationalRuling />
              <BankInfo />
              <Address />
              <Commission />
              <AccountInfo />
            </DataContext.Provider>
```

everthing is ok in this implementation, its clean.

BUT

everytime user start typing something the whole components re-render there is a clear lag and delay in typing.

so i think `one way` is to update the State with `onBlur` but that is also slow a little i think. `another way` is to have seperate state inside every children component for example for BankInfo component have a single state and `lift the state up` but i have no idea how to do that and make it a `single Object` so i can `send it the backend`
How can we improve perfomance in a data like this without re-rendering everything ?
what is correct way to collect data in this situation?

i will appreciate your help.

Comment: Try adding callbacks to the child components like `onSubmit` and only update parent state when child state is actually submitted and not on each keystroke/change.
Implementation will depend on your UI and it will be another problem to determine when to pass the updated data when the children have no submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to manage the state of each component at this higher level (to perform an action using data across each component), then I recommend simply passing this data into each component via props instead of using a context provider.

The context API should be used to prevent a situation where you are passing the same prop into literally all of your components (and typically a prop which is not changing frequently). I typically associate it with `auth` or `user`.

Making this modification to declarative state management, will greatly improve the readability of this application as well as allow the renderer to determine which components to partially render. i.e. only changes which are necessary to be made will be made, because you will have properly hooked up the reactive elements of your application

Here is a code example:

```
function Overview() {
    ...

    function submit() {
    }

    return (
        <>
            <BankInfo name={bankName1} ... onChange={submit} />
            ...
        </>
    )
}

function BankInfo({name, ..., onChange}) {
    return (
        <>
            <input value={name} onChange={onChange} />
            ...
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: but inside every children component there are alot of input fields and i think this Implementation is not the way.

Comment: I recommend trying this approach. We should always prefer passing data by props first before leaning on a tool like context. I have updated my code example to have some more depth. Let me know if you have other questions, or what your concerns are.